# Deploy war file to Ec2 via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I have a war file in my Jenkins server. And i would like to deploy it to another Ec2 Server. However, i couldn't find appropriate plugin or method how can i achieve this?, my only need is to deploy it to another Ec2 Server.

Answer (score 0):

Install the CLI and github plugin in Jenkins.

Upload your war file to Github or s3 or BitBucket.

Then issue the CLI commands to download the war file and deploy it in the /webapps folder.

You can Follow the same to download the source code, build it using maven or grade and deploy the war file in the /webapps folder.